# How to have the user add another upload input by clicking?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, input

I've been using this:

> http://plugins.krajee.com/file-basic-usage-demo

It's a file upload widget, and I'd like to know how I can make this so that a user can click a button and generate another file upload input (but with a hidden limit of, say, 10). So, say, I have the following:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="file1_recipient" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Upload Photo (1)</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <input id="file1_recipient" type="file" class="file">
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to the user to click and get:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="file1_recipient" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Upload Photo (1)</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <input id="file1_recipient" type="file" class="file">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="file2_recipient" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Upload Photo (2)</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <input id="file2_recipient" type="file" class="file">
    </div>
</div>
```

And if they click again they'd get three, and so on until 10. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` of element in `document` should be unique. You can remove `id` from initial `<input type="file">` element, use `.clone()`, `.last()`, `.insertAfter()` to create a clone of original element and append cloned element to `document` after last `.form-group` element. You can create a variable, for example `var limit = 10`. When `10` clicks are registered set `button` `disabled` attribute to `"disabled"`, call `.off("click")` at `button`. You can use `.text(function)`, `.replace()` to increment the digit within parenthesis of cloned `<label>` element with `current + 1`, where `current` is the variable incremented until from `0` until `limit`:`10` is reached at `click` event handler.

```js
$(function() {
  var limit = 10;
  var current = 0;
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    if (++current < limit) {
      $(".form-group").last().clone()
      .find("label")
      .text(function(_, text) {
        return text.replace(/\d+/, current + 1)
      })
      .end()
      .insertAfter(".form-group:last");
    } else {
      $(this).off("click").prop("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add File</button>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="file1_recipient" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Upload Photo (1)</label>
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    <input type="file" class="file">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I saw your answer.. Here in the output window it is working but when you add the css files, the selected file is also getting cloned along when you clone. Check my JS fiddle here that I have setup. Any ideas on how to exactly solve this?? JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j7h6yh4z/

Comment: @JestinoSam _"but when you add the css files, the selected file is also getting cloned along when you clone."_ Not certain what you mean?

Comment: I mean if u add more inputs after selecting the file, so in the 2nd cloned input, the selected file of 1st input also appears. Just see the fiddle

Comment: @JestinoSam See what you mean. That is apparently due to one of the external resources listed at jsfiddle https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.3.6/js/fileinput.min.js

Comment: Yeah I do know that but i just asked any idea on how to solve it.. I thought u might be using the plugin.

Comment: @JestinoSam No, do not use plugin. Suggestion would be to remove plugin.